# Group projects within an organization

Tags: azure-devops

We used to structure projects on Gitlab in groups named after the client. Is it possible to group projects together in Azure DevOps within an organization? The desired state looks something like this

```
Organization
|
|- Company 1
|   \
|    |- Project for Company 1
|    |- Project2 for Company 1
|
|- Company 2
|   \
|    |- Project for Company 2
```

Currently, the structure is flat

```
Organization
|
|- Project for Company 1
|- Project2 for Company 1
|- Project for Company 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not, each project lives under the root organization.

What you would want to do is probably create a Team Project for each company, then use separate teams and area paths to split out the work items for each project. Work items can be split by subteam, but repos and pipelines roll up at the Team Project level so you would have to use the Team to limit access.

```
Organization
|
|- Company 1
|   \
|    |- Team for Project1 (which creates a new area path where the work items are stored)
|    |- Team for Project2 (which creates a new area path where the work items are stored)
|
|- Company 2
|   \
|    |- Team for Project (which creates a new area path where the work items are stored)
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/about-projects?view=azure-devops